# Jquery post request returning html

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery, html, json

I am trying to make an AJAX request in my `Magento 2.1.8` custom module.

The Http Post Request is returning all of the data i expect it to in JSON format, However it is also adding on some of my html code after it.

What could be causing this?

returning JSON object:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $return = [];
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                 $return[] = [
                    'id' => $row['id'],
                    'name' => $row['name'],
                    'created' => $row['created'],
                    'posts' => $row['posts']
                ];
             }

             header('Content-type: application/json');
             echo json_encode($return);
```

HTTP Post Request:

```
$.post("https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/forum/get/categories",
     function(data, status){
       console.log(data);
     });
```

The data being returned is correctly formatted JSON object and then goes straight into html:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Tanks - Sub Ohm","created":"15-01-18","posts":"1"}]<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB" dir="ltr" class="ltr">
    <head >
        <script>............
```

How can i remove the HTML part?

Thanks.

Comment: share your controller file too

Answer (score 0):

use exit will solve the problem  for you

`echo json_encode($return); exit;`

and use proper magento 2 way for json response.
[Example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/retreive-and-return-response-from-controller-in-magento2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Qaisar, I found the solution to my problem. but I will also start using the way to return json response from the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem by deleting:

```
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

From the execute() function inside my controller.

Comment: It was already mention in my last answer.

Comment: That was regarding a 404 error occuring when trying to send a http request. It was also not the correct answer as when i fixed the controller, I could still send requests even with the above code

Comment: Then your question was not clear enough. also i seen the hardcode the url simple use this `<?php  echo $block->getUrl('forum/get/categories'); ?>` to get url

Comment: The Question clearly states that the problem I was facing was regarding the 404 error and at no point did it mention html being added to the end of the http response. The two questions I asked are different and required different solutions. Thanks for the php getUrl method, I will use that in future.

Comment: No problem dear I are not here to give correct answer everytime some wrong answer's too.