# Magento 2.3: How to Echo From Controller On Button Click?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, phtml, custom-button

I'm very new to Magento, I have a custom module and some tabs and fields in it, i have an 'import' tab, in that their is 'Import' button, just want to know the workflow of that button, like on button click just `echo` something from controller. `Right now i'm getting no response on button click...`

**app\code{Vendor_Name}{Module_Name}\view\adminhtml\templates\form\Import.phtml**

```
<div class="pp-buttons-container">
    <button id="<?php echo $block->getId() ?>" onclick="return false;">
        <span><span><span><?php echo 'Import'; ?></span></span></span>
    </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery",], function($){
        "use strict";
        $(document).on('click','.col-action-grouped a',function(){
        });
    });
</script>
```

**app\code\{Vendor_Name}{Module_Name}\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab\Import.php**

```
<?php
namespace EC\Customimport\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Edit\Tab;


class Import extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $_template = 'form/import.phtml';

    public function isReadonly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Import');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Import');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**app\code{Vendor_Name}{Module_Name}\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Import.php**

```
<?php

namespace EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use EC\Customimport\Model\CustomimportFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomimportFactory $modelCustomimportFactory
    ) {
        $this->modelCustomimportFactory = $modelCustomimportFactory;
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        ignore_user_abort(true);
        set_time_limit(0);
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model  = $this->modelCustomimportFactory->create()->load($id);
        $model->import();
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: your calling `getId()` method but it is not in your block class. Also your onclick function does not do anything so sure you will not get a response from that

Comment: you can check this on how to pass response from the controller to ajax https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138043/retreive-and-return-response-from-controller-in-magento2?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by doing make an ajax request and sent in to controller.

**app\code{Vendor_Name}{Module_Name}\view\adminhtml\templates\form\Import.phtml**

```
<div class="pp-buttons-container">
    <button class="import" id="<?php echo $block->getId() ?>" onclick="return false;">
        <span><span><span><?php echo 'Import'; ?></span></span></span>
    </button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery",'mage/url'], function($, url){
        "use strict";
        $(document).on('click','.col-action-grouped a',function(){
        });

        $(document).on('click','.import',function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/customimport/index/import',
            type: "POST",
            data: {data:'success'},
            success: function(response){
                console.log('Sucess');
            }
        });
        });

    });
</script>
```

**app\code{Vendor_Name}{Module_Name}\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Import.php**

```
<?php

namespace EC\Customimport\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use EC\Customimport\Model\CustomimportFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

class Import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomimportFactory $modelCustomimportFactory
    ) {
        $this->modelCustomimportFactory = $modelCustomimportFactory;
        $this->resultFactory = $context->getResultFactory();
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        echo 'Success';
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: url: '/admin/customimport/index/import', where is this coming from?

Comment: it's my controller path

Comment: app\code{Vendor_Name}{Module_Name}\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Import.php

where is admin? '/admin/customimport/index/import

Comment: maybe a mistake brother.

Comment: No i am not judging i want to know how this work i am trying to learn this please can you explain

Comment: bro if you want to make an ajax request on click, and you button is in `.phtml` file then you just have to write a `<script>` you'll find a syntax in `Import.phtml`, then in `url: ` you have to give the path of your controller, than make a controller which gets that ajax request, and `echo` so that you know that your ajax request is working

Comment: I have a button in my phtml  and i have a script  url: 'adminhtml/invalidatequote/quote', 
I am not sure how the url works  This is my controller path  namespace vendor\maodule_name\Controller\Adminhtml\Index/Quote.php

What would i call in the URL?

Comment: did you make a `route` file for `frontname' ?

Comment: yes and its called <route id="invalidatequote" frontName="invalidatequote">

Comment: `customimport => route name` | `index => folder in which controller file exist` | `import => controller name`

Comment: `url: '/invalidatequote/ControllerFolder/ControllerFile'`

Comment: vendor\module_name(invalidatequote)\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Quote.php
so my url = url: "/invalidatequote/invalidatequote/quote", or am i wrong

Comment: `url: '/invalidatequote/index/quote'`,

`invalidatequote` => route name | `index` => folder in which controller file exist | `quote` => controller name

Comment: No that didnt work i get this error url: "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
",

Comment: `/invalidatequote/invalidatequote/quote` this is wrong url your url should be like this `/invalidatequote/index/quote`

Comment: Okay, raise a proper question with your `phtml` and `controller`...

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298880/my-ajax-request-isnt-working-properly-in-phtml I have created one