# My ajax request isn't working properly in phtml

Tags: magento2, controllers, admin-controller

vendor\module_name\view\adminhtml\templates\tab\customer_view.phtml

```
    <?php $buttonTitle = __('Invalidate Quotes');?>
<div class="fieldset-wrapper customer-information">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
        <span class="title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo __('Invalidate customer quote') ?></span>
    </div>
    <table class="admin__table-secondary">
        <tbody>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml(); ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo __('Customer ID:') ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $block->getCustomerId(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
echo __('Invalidate Active Quote:') ?></th>
            <td>

            <div class="pp-buttons-container">
                <button class="import" id="<?php echo $block->getId() ?>" onclick="return false;">
                    <span><span><span><?php echo 'Remove Active Quote'; ?></span></span></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["jquery",'mage/url'], function($, url){
        "use strict";
        $(document).on('click','.col-action-grouped a',function(){
        });

        $(document).on('click','.import',function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/invalidatequote/index/quote",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {data:'success'},
            success: function(response){

                console.log('Sucess');
            }
        });
        });

    });
</script>
```

My controller vendor\module_name\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Quote.php

```
 <?php

namespace vendor\module_name\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Quote extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->isAjax()) {

            echo "Testing";
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

> Request URL: https://localhost/admin/customer/index/edit/id/710825/key/51d5c1c3a251b6c0ce8b36ce3d832b2b1f359c8f073691f8c1df296ebf4a22c5/invalidatequote/index/quote?isAjax=true
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Status Code: 200
>
> Remote Address: 192.168.100.101:443
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

routes.xml  vendor\module_name\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="invalidatequote" frontName="invalidatequote">
            <module name="module_name" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: Testing printed in response or not?

Comment: not getting any response

Comment: can u please print Testing outside function and check

Comment: $(document).on('click','.import',function(){
    console.log('Sucess');
});

Check did you get `Success` in console without ajax.

Comment: $(document).on('click','.import',function(){ console.log('Sucess'); }); is working i can see the log

Comment: @NareshRupareliya what am i doing in function?

Comment: Check with posted answer and let me know working or not

Comment: the post is not working @NareshRupareliya when i click the button i get error "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later.
"

Comment: paste you route file with path...

Comment: may be issue with your controller. can u pelase yourbase_url/invalidatequote/index/quote direct write in browser url and check Testing display or not. and please echo "Testing" first in execute method

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir added in now

Comment: do as Naresh said... hit you controller directly... remove everything from `execute()` just add `echo `Testing`'

Comment: @NareshRupareliya I dont understand how to test what you said

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir how do you mean?

Comment: Please write base_url/invalidatequote/index/quote in browser directly and check your contoroller called or not. we just want to check if your controller called successfully so we need to only check in phtml file

Comment: @PartabSaifuddinZakir  and  NareshRupareliya you guys mean do this -> localhost/invalidatequote/index/quote

Comment: e.g, this is your base_url => localhost.com/, type something like this and hit  `localhost.com/admin/invalidatequote/index/quote`

Comment: i get 404 on the status

Comment: localhost/admin/invalidatequote/index/quote

Comment: please share me exact error's screenshot. please